# Unable to scrape data from multiple pages for a personal project

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to scrape some data from daft.ie.

My code:

```
import requests
import bs4
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36"
}

divs = np.linspace(start=0, stop=3120, num=157)
divs = divs.astype(int)

Initial_page = "https://www.daft.ie/property-for-rent/dublin?pageSize=20&from=" # the very first page
houses = [[]]*len(divs)
adds = [[]]*len(divs)
for i in divs:
    j = 0
    url = Initial_page+str(i) # construct the url by pasting
    r = requests.get(url,{'headers':headers})
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
    houses[j].append(soup.find_all('div',{'class': 'SubUnit__StyledCol-sc-10x486s-4 xDgcL'}))
    adds[j].append(soup.find_all('p',{'class': 'TitleBlock__Address-sc-1avkvav-7 eARcqq', 'data-testid': 'address'}))
```

**There are 150+ pages with an array of around 20 different text from each page to be appended into a list.** But only a first few pages' data gets appended and the rest is NULL. How to rectify this and ensure I can scrape all the required data and append into a list?

Answer (score -1):

Again id suggest to use selenium to:

1. Go on the page
2. Scroll down to the Page 2 Button
3. Pass the source to the beautifulsoup part, which scrapes the stuff you need
4. click the next page button
   You can loop this until you are done with every site, i assume this would be the easiest solution